# jQuery search adding anchors

Tags: jquery, search

I need help with my jQuery search script.. I'm looking to add anchors to my search.
If if type something in, it shows up at: site.com/#search=*keyword*

```
$('input#media-search').on('click', function() {
    var media = $('input#media').val();
    if ($.trim(media) != '') {
        $.post('search.php', {media: media}, function(data) {
            $('div#media-list').html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this.

```
location.hash = "#search=" + value;
```

assuming data is what you want in your location. If its media, sub that.

```
$('input#media-search').on('click', function() {
   var media = $('input#media').val();
      if ($.trim(media) != '') {
        $.post('search.php', {media: media}, function(data) {
            $('div#media-list').html(data);
            location.hash = "#search=" + data;
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: edit: I'm sorry, it does work.
but how can I add it if i go to site.com/#search=plapla, it opens that content

Comment: not sure I follow what you mean. I'd like to help, just not sure what you are going for.

Comment: what is the value or dataObj for the location you want to go to? If I am mistaken, don't you just want to add "#search=searchTerm" to the end of it?

Comment: Correct, for example if i would to go site.com/search=wasd it would show me wasd search